# Аудит кода/проекта

Tags: java, аудит

В данный момент времени я занимаюсь разработкой библиотеки на java для работы с API Я.Директ.

Но ввиду отсутствия опыта или нехватки знаний или того и другого.
А возможно низкой самооценки :)

Когда я смотрю на свой код, то вижу что-то несуразное, вообщем не нравится он мне. Но что именно мне не нравится понять не могу.

В следствии чего у меня возник вопрос, могу ли я куда-то выложить свой код на аудит?

Т.е. понятное дело что, я могу выложить какойто кусок на [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) но это не то. Т.к. меня интересует аудит проекта в целом.

И да я понимаю, что просто так мало кто захочет тратить свое время на аудит кода, какого-то парня из интернета, но мало ли :)

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Для всех пользователей, указавших что этот вопрос требует правок, так как он слишком общий. Пожалуйста укажите, что именно вы посчитали здесь общим?
Ведь мой вопрос достаточно конкретный "могу ли я куда-то выложить свой код на аудит?"

Answer (score 3):

Добавлю, что помимо просмотра открытого кода старших коллег из open source, имеет смысл почитать книги и статьи по теории. Паттерны, SOLID и т.д.

Тогда и код будет проще воспринимать, т.к. Вы будете понимать не только, что сделано, но и зачем сделано.

Answer (score 2):

вам нужно просто много листать коды опытных разработчиков чтобы у вас было понимание стандартов и т.д. в интернете полно опен соурс проектов. Сам могу вам посоветовать https://github.com/HoraApps/LeafPic